# Mover imágenes con hilos en Java

Tags: java, imagen, hilos

Tengo una clase en java con tres hilos con velocidades random, ahora mi idea es implementar esos hilos a una parte gráfica para simular una carrera. Creo que en el `setbounds` de las imágenes tiene que ir la velocidad de los hilos para que se vayan moviendo las imágenes de izquierda a derecha por todo el frame.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código de los gráficos:**

```
public class Interfaz 
{
    JFrame framePrincipal = null;
    JLabel imagenFriki1 = null;
    JLabel imagenFriki2 = null;
    JLabel imagenFriki3 = null;
    JLabel carretera = null;

    public Interfaz() 
    {
        iniciar();
        framePrincipal.setVisible(true);        
    }

    public void iniciar()
    {
        framePrincipal = new JFrame("CARRERA");
        framePrincipal.setSize(1300,900);
        framePrincipal.setLayout(null);
        framePrincipal.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        framePrincipal.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        framePrincipal.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        framePrincipal.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        imagenFriki1 = new JLabel();
        imagenFriki1.setBounds(10,50,250,250);
        ImageIcon imgfriki1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/GIFS/friki1.gif"));
        ImageIcon imgescalada = new ImageIcon(imgfriki1.getImage().getScaledInstance(imagenFriki1.getWidth(),
                imagenFriki1.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        imagenFriki1.setIcon(imgescalada);      
        framePrincipal.add(imagenFriki1);

        imagenFriki2 = new JLabel();
        imagenFriki2.setBounds(10,320,250,250);
        ImageIcon imgfriki2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/GIFS/friki2.gif"));
        ImageIcon imgescalada2 = new ImageIcon(imgfriki2.getImage().getScaledInstance(imagenFriki2.getWidth(),
                imagenFriki2.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        imagenFriki2.setIcon(imgescalada2);     
        framePrincipal.add(imagenFriki2);

        imagenFriki3 = new JLabel();
        imagenFriki3.setBounds(10,590,250,250);
        ImageIcon imgfriki3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/GIFS/friki3.gif"));
        ImageIcon imgescalada3 = new ImageIcon(imgfriki3.getImage().getScaledInstance(imagenFriki3.getWidth(),
                imagenFriki3.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        imagenFriki3.setIcon(imgescalada3);     
        framePrincipal.add(imagenFriki3);
    }
}
```

**Código de los hilos:**

```
public class Carrera extends Thread
{
    String nombre;
    int velocidad;

    public Carrera(String nombre,int velocidad) 
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.velocidad = velocidad;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=25;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(nombre+" ");
            try {
                sleep(1000/velocidad);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        System.out.println("Terminó: "+nombre+"\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Carrera friki1 = new Carrera("f1", random.nextInt(10));
        Carrera friki2 = new Carrera("f2", random.nextInt(10));
        Carrera friki3 = new Carrera("f3", random.nextInt(10));

        friki1.start();
        friki2.start();
        friki3.start();
    }
}
```

Como puedo aplicar la velocidad de los hilos a las imágenes para que éstas se muevan hasta llegar al final del frame??

Comment: Así a vuelo de pájaro prueba haciendo 'Interfaz' tu clase principal, haz que el constructor del Thread reciba también un JLabel, luego dentro del ciclo del run cambias la posición de esas labels que recibiste con setLocation( lbl.getX() + 1, lbl.getY() );